# setVisibility is not working in swipe left to right

Tags: android, listview, swipe, ontouchlistener

First I want to show delete button on swiping left to right .I detected swipe left to right but my button is not visible.

**The Screen shot is showing problem**

[image]

```
  layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    downX = event.getX();
                    downY = event.getY();
                  //  deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mSwipeDetected = Action.None;
                    return true; // allow other events like Click to be processed
                }
               // MotionEvent.A
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    upX = event.getX();
                    upY = event.getY();
                    float deltaX = downX - upX;
                    float deltaY = downY - upY;
                    // horizontal swipe detection
                    if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                        // left or right
                        if (deltaX < 0) {
                            Log.e("lr","Swipe Left to Right");//this is working
                            deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            mSwipeDetected = Action.LR;
                            return true;
                        }
                        if (deltaX > 0) {
                            Log.e("Swipe Right to Left","Swipe Right to Left");
                            deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            // Logger.show(Log.INFO,logTag, "Swipe Right to Left");
                            mSwipeDetected = Action.RL;
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Second problem is that i also want to do some task on **`onitemclicklistener`** so how i impalement it in to **`OnTouchListener`**.`
**This is my complete class code**

```
  package com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.Database.DBhelper;
import com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.Fragments.FavoriteFragment;
import com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.MainActivity;
import com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.Model.Favorite;
import com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.Model.LionStreet;
import com.example.rehankhan.parkken_app.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Rehan Khan on 3/29/2017.
 */
public class FavoriteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    public Context aContext;
    Button deleteBtn;
    View v;
    ///////////////
    public static enum Action {
        LR, // Left to Right
        RL, // Right to Left
        TB, // Top to bottom
        BT, // Bottom to Top
        None // when no action was detected
    }

    private static final String logTag = "OnSwipeTouchListener";
    private static final int MIN_DISTANCE = 100;
    private float downX, downY, upX, upY;
    private Action mSwipeDetected = Action.None;

    //////////////
    float historicX = Float.NaN, historicY = Float.NaN;
    static final int DELTA = 50;
    enum Direction {LEFT, RIGHT;}
    private List<Favorite> favoriteList,filterlist, lionStreets,lionStreetfirsttime, fullList;

    public FavoriteAdapter(Context aContext, List<Favorite> lionStreets,List<Favorite> lionStreetfirsttime){
        this.aContext=aContext;
       // this.context = context;
        this.lionStreets = lionStreets;
        this.favoriteList = new ArrayList<Favorite>();
        this. favoriteList.addAll(lionStreets);
        this.fullList =new ArrayList<Favorite>();
        fullList.addAll(lionStreetfirsttime);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return lionStreets.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return lionStreets.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String CurrentlocationName, PreviouslocationName = null;
       // int hiddenId;
         View v = View.inflate(aContext, R.layout.fav_loc_view, null);
        deleteBtn = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.deletebtn);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.fav_list_layout);
        final TextView location_name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fav_location_name);
      //  final TextView hiddenIdTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hiddenid);
        //String fav_loc_name = favoriteList.get(position).getFav_loc_name();
      //  TextView headding=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.heading);
        Log.e("positionbefre", String.valueOf(position));
        Log.e("beforlistsize", String.valueOf(lionStreets.size()));
       ////////////////for touch listnor
        layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                        downX = event.getX();
                        downY = event.getY();
                      //  deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mSwipeDetected = Action.None;
                        return true; // allow other events like Click to be processed
                    }
                   // MotionEvent.A
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                        upX = event.getX();
                        upY = event.getY();
                        float deltaX = downX - upX;
                        float deltaY = downY - upY;
                        // horizontal swipe detection
                        if (Math.abs(deltaX) > MIN_DISTANCE) {
                            // left or right
                            if (deltaX < 0) {
                                Log.e("lr","Swipe Left to Right");//this is working
                                deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                mSwipeDetected = Action.LR;
                                return true;
                            }
                            if (deltaX > 0) {
                                Log.e("Swipe Right to Left","Swipe Right to Left");
                                deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                // Logger.show(Log.INFO,logTag, "Swipe Right to Left");
                                mSwipeDetected = Action.RL;
                                return true;
                            }
                        } else {deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);}
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        /////////////////////////////// for slide end

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DBhelper   data = DBhelper.getInstance(aContext);
                data.deleteFavoite(lionStreets.get(position).getFav_loc_name());
                ((MainActivity) aContext ).getFavoriteFragment().resetList();
                //  notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
       ////////////////////for touch listnor

        if(lionStreets.size()!= 0 && position <= lionStreets.size()) {
            Log.e("positionafter", String.valueOf(position));
            Log.e("listsizeafter", String.valueOf(lionStreets.size()));
            CurrentlocationName = lionStreets.get(position).getFav_loc_name();
          //  hiddenId = lionStreets.get(position).getID();
            if (CurrentlocationName != null) {
                if (CurrentlocationName.length() == 1) {
                    location_name.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
                }
                location_name.setText(CurrentlocationName);
               // hiddenIdTextView.setText(String.valueOf(hiddenId));
            }
        } else{
            Log.e("zeroo", String.valueOf(position));
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            //    position=0;
        }
        return v;
     }

    public class filter_here extends android.widget.Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//filterarr=lionStreets;
            FilterResults Result = new FilterResults();
            // if constraint is empty return the original names
         /*   if(constraint.length() == 0 ){
                Result.values = filterlist;
                Result.count = filterlist.size();
                return Result;
            }*/

            //   Filtered_Names = new ArrayList<String>();
            String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
            String filterableString;
//            filterlist.clear();
            filterlist = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i< favoriteList.size(); i++){
                filterableString = favoriteList.get(i).getFav_loc_name();
                //  ||filterableString.toLowerCase().equals(filterString)
                if(filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString) ){
                    if(favoriteList.get(i).getFav_loc_name().length()!=1) {
                        //           Filtered_Names.add(filterableString);
                        filterlist.add(favoriteList.get(i));
                    }
                    else {

                        Log.e("singleword",favoriteList.get(i).getFav_loc_name());

                    }
                }
            }
            if(constraint.equals("") ){
                lionStreets.clear();
                filterlist.clear();
                filterlist.addAll(fullList);

                //lionStreets=filterlist;
                Result.values =filterlist;

                Result.count = filterlist.size();
            }else
            Result.values = filterlist;
            Result.count = filterlist.size();


            return Result;
        }
/*
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
        ArrayList<String> name = (ArrayList<String>) filterResults.values;
            Log.e("filter words", String.valueOf(name.size()));
           Log.e("filter list",name.toString());

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }*/

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//            filterlist = (List<LionStreet>) results.values;
            if(filterlist.size() < favoriteList.size()) {
                Log.e("filltersize", String.valueOf(filterlist.size()));
//                lionStreets = filterlist;
                lionStreets.clear();
                lionStreets.addAll(filterlist);
                // fire the event
                notifyDataSetChanged();

            } else {
                lionStreets.addAll( favoriteList);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

    }

    public android.widget.Filter getFilter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        android.widget.Filter fill = new filter_here();
        return fill;

    }}

/////////////////////// make touch lisner
/*private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD = 450;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 400;

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        float distanceX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
        float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
        if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY) && Math.abs(distanceX) > SWIPE_DISTANCE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
            if (distanceX > 0)
                onSwipeRight();
            else
                onSwipeLeft();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
}*/
////////////////////end
```

**After used runOnUiThread**
[image]

Comment: Have you tried using Handler ?

Comment: thanks for your reply .No i did not try with handler

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`runOnUiThread`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)).

```
if (deltaX < 0) {
    aContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
            Log.e("lr","Swipe Left to Right");//this is working
            deleteBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mSwipeDetected = Action.LR;
            return true;
        } 
    });

}
```

**`runOnUiThread`**

> Runs the specified action on the UI thread. If the current thread is
>   the UI thread, then the action is executed immediately. If the current
>   thread is not the UI thread, the action is posted to the event queue
>   of the UI thread.

Comment: thanks for reply please tell me .what i need to put in start?runOnUiThread(new Runnable()

Comment: @Rehankhan For view refresh case.

Comment: @Rehankhan `your_contextOBJ` According to screenshot your code within ADAPTER section. You should pass Context object there.

Comment: @Rehankhan Solved this yet?

Comment: extremely sorry for late reply

Comment: .I asked you i do not have any idea how use .runOnUiThread(new Runnable(). my context object is "aContext" of adapter.

Comment: @Rehankhan kindly check my answer.